# program php and alert javascript on form html

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

i have a problem with my simple program in php that include an alert javascript.
This is the code:

```
<?php

function iva(){
$country='IT';
$vatnum=$_POST['n'];

$a="Work";
$b="NotWork";

$url='http://isvat.appspot.com/'.$country.'/'.$vatnum.'/';
 $response = file_get_contents($url);
//global $a, $b;
if( $response == 'true' ){
echo $a;
}
if ($response != 'true'){
echo $b;
}
}
?>
<script>
function ivaz(){

alert("<?php iva() ?>");

}
</script> 

<form method="post">
<input name="n"  type="textarea" >
<input  onclick="ivaz();" value="Validate" type="submit"> </input> </form>
```

My program take a value from input text box and pass the value to php script that return true or false in a javascript alert. The program work, but return previous value passed in input box.
Can someone help me to solve it?

Thanks guys.

Comment: You should first learn [the differences between server side scripting and client side scripting](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. If you want to call a PHP function from Javascript without the page refreshing, you need an XMLHttpRequest.

Example:

```
<?php
// your php process when called by XMLHttpRequest
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $vatnum = $_POST['n'];
    $country='IT';
    $a = "Work";
    $b = "NotWork";

    $url = 'http://isvat.appspot.com/'.$country.'/'.$vatnum.'/';
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    //global $a, $b;
    if( $response == 'true' ){
        echo $a;
    } else {
        echo $b; 
    }
    exit;
}

?>

<form method="post" id="form1">
    <input name="n" type="text" id="n" />
    <input value="Validate" type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// when the form is submitted
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var n = document.getElementById('n').value; // get the textbox value
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'n=' + n;
    var php_url = document.URL;
    xmlhttp.open('POST', php_url, true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(response); // alert the server response
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send(params);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note: Using jQuery is highly recommended for maximum browser compatibility.

Comment: @Icefyre if jquery is tagged, i could have answer it with it. but since its not there. i did not

Comment: @Icefyre even fuzzy people here downvote answers with jquery code with a non jquery tagged question even if its correct.

Comment: Didn't know that, but will keep it in mind for the future. Thank you.

Comment: the code work!! thanks. If i want load this code on another javascript? it's possible?

Comment: @BlekZ yes its possible in another one, just create your own function in javascript then just use that xmlhttprequest again for other purposes.

Comment: Sorry, i'm newbie on javascript. I must create function in javascript and use xmlttprequest. On input submit can i use onclick to recall javascript function?

Comment: @BlekZ yes you can do that, just the same on javascript, just create a function onclick to whatever button it is. the important thing is that xmlhttprequest, you can't just outright put the `iva()` function of PHP inside that javascript, you need to use that xmlhttprequest.

Comment: @BlekZ well you could just use `onmouserover="myFunction()"` etc. you could just search it in google for more details

Comment: @Ghost can you help me to rewrite the same code with onblur instead of input submit?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onclick="ivaz();"` from input tag

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the php script without reloading the page as php is generated serverside and javascript runs clientside.